# Two installed javas on same pc. The one with lower version can not be called

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I have two javas installed on my pc. `jdk1.7.0_45 (x64)` and `jdk1.6.0_45(x86)`. I want that default java on my machine would be `jdk1.6.0_45(x86)`. I added `JAVA_HOME` with value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45` and added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin` to system path, but still when i type in command prompt "java -version" it says:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I have no idea why the things are like that, because my OS should see `jdk1.7.0_45 (x64)` version. Why is that so?

I use windows 8

---

edit:

after setting java home to jdk1.7.0_45 (x64) folder and updating path accordingly javac works, but then I set java home and path to jdk1.6.0_45(x86) javac does not work.

Comment: after typing javac -version I get 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It means JDK is not installed at all...Or, you have not added the path correctly...  Period..

Comment: I think the Java panel in the system control is the reason. The options there are stronger than the enviroment variable.

Comment: BTW if you are using eclipse, there is an option to choose the default JDK version.. in control panel as well there is an option to choose default JDK version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the very beginning of your path. This is because Java is installed in your `%SystemRoot%\system32`, too. If you add the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the beginning of your path the Java installed in your `JAVA_HOME` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME does not help when we run java from command line, you should fix PATH system var

Answer (score 0):

> I added JAVA_HOME with value C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

In Windows, you should excape spaces in the path: `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"`. But the best way is to set Java to a folder that doesn't have spaces in its path. For example, I use `C:\Java\Java6`

> and added C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin to system path

Probably you added **after** path to the Java 7. Make sure that Java 7 doesn't exist in the system path.